# Facebook Fan Page Wall Post from website using php sdk returning code parameter

Tags: facebook

I try to post facebook fan page wall from my website using php sdk 3.0.Its Working fine

**Sometimes the redirecturl contains Code parameter and stopped all process.**

The url look like www.mysite.com/posttofacebook.php?code='somerandomstring'

i am searching lot of times but i cant get correct solution.I have mention my complete code below.

Pls help me.

Thanks.

```
<?php
require_once 'src/facebook.php';

// configuration

$appid = 'myappid';

$appsecret = 'myappsecret';

$pageId = 'mypageid';


$msg ='Test ';

$title = 'TestTestTestTestTestTest';
$uri = 'http://www.welcome.com';

$desc = 'TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest';

$pic = 'http://www.welcome.com';



$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $appid,
'secret' => $appsecret,
'cookie' => false,
 ));

 $user = $facebook->getUser();



 if ($user) 
 {


try 
  {

$page_info = $facebook->api("/$pageId?fields=access_token");

if (!empty($page_info['access_token'])) {

$attachment = array(

'access_token' => $page_info['access_token'],

'message' => $msg,

 'name' => $title,

'link' => $uri,

'description' => $desc,

'caption' => $caption,

'picture'=>$pic,



);

 $status = $facebook->api("/$pageId/feed", "post", $attachment);

 $msg="<h2 align='center'>Sucessfully Posted On Facebook Wall</h2>";
 } 
else 
{
$status = 'No access token recieved';
}

} 
catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
{
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
} 
 else 
{



header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' =>

'photo_upload,user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,manage_pages'))}");

 }



?>
```